# Search a list in column in pandas and return a string value if found and return null if not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, arraylist

I have

```py
['2013 (63 reg)', '76,869 miles', '2.0L','Manual', 'Diesel</li>\n</ul>']
['2011 (61 reg)', 'Estate', '2.0L', '135BHP','Manual', 'Diesel', '4 owners</li>\n</ul>']
['2011 (11 reg)', 'Saloon', '112,000 miles', '2.1L', '201BHP','Manual', 'Diesel', '4 owners', 'Partservice history</li>\n</ul>']
['2007 (07 reg)', 'Saloon', '98,000 miles','3.0L', '222BHP', 'Automatic', 'Diesel']
```

in a column Data in dataframe df
i have this code to check if the word 'miles' exist if yes it returns the string that contains miles in it if not it should return empty and store it in a list

```py
miles=[]
sub = 'miles'
for f in df['Data'] :
    for text in f:
        if sub in text:
            miles.append(text)
        else:
            miles.append('')`
```

it returns `' '` for all the text values , not each list
where i got some thing like this

```
['',
 '76,869 miles',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '112,000 miles',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '98,000 miles',
 '',
 ]
```

where i want

```
['76,869 miles',
'',
'112,000 miles',
'98,000 miles']
```

Comment: Your `if` condition is currently works fine ! you already appending `' '` during your `else`. Kindly review your `nested` loop. run it without the append to see how your data will looks like !

Comment: when i remove the else the results is    ['76,869 miles',
'112,000 miles',
'98,000 miles'], which i dont want as i would like the code to recognize if the list doesnot  containe 'miles 'and returns and empty value per list.. I tried alot i cant figure it out

Comment: In that case, you have to use `generator` and don't append under `for` loop. with involving `next` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are using `nested` loop to check each `element` on each list. where you code is currently check if `miles` in the element and return it, if not so you are just appending `''` corresponding to elements without `miles`.

But your logic here is to search `elements` of each list and if the `list` not containing the desired `target` so we need the code to reply back with `Hey, I'm not there`.

So, we have to use `generator` along with `next` function.

```
data = [['2013 (63 reg)', '76,869 miles', '2.0L',
         'Manual', 'Diesel</li>\n</ul>'],
        ['2011 (61 reg)', 'Estate', '2.0L', '135BHP',
         'Manual', 'Diesel', '4 owners</li>\n</ul>'],
        ['2011 (11 reg)', 'Saloon', '112,000 miles', '2.1L', '201BHP',
         'Manual', 'Diesel', '4 owners', 'Partservice history</li>\n</ul>'],
        ['2007 (07 reg)', 'Saloon', '98,000 miles',
         '3.0L', '222BHP', 'Automatic', 'Diesel']]


new = [next((t for t in item if "miles" in t), "Miles Not Found")
       for item in data]

print(new)
```

Output:

```
['76,869 miles', 'Miles Not Found', '112,000 miles', '98,000 miles']
```

Comment: when using a dataframe column df['Data'] , when true it return the whole list , and returns Miles Not Found correctly. new = [next((t for t in item if "miles" in t), "Miles Not Found")
       for item in df['Data']...and when i used a list like stated above its just returned [['not found',
 'not found',
 'not found',
 'not found',] , I think we can tweak the code with df['Data'] to return only the miles string instead of the whole list, still trying to figure out how

Comment: lists stored in a dataframe column

Comment: @HalaElHenawy are you treating a columns with `.to_list()` ? to have it `list` of `lists`?

Comment: No, but even when i did that still giving me the same results as stated, I have one column and each row in the column has a list in it .

Comment: Thank you, I just changed data to df['Data'].to_list()

Comment: @HalaElHenawy Sounds good, Feel free to accept the answer if it's helps you by `ticking` the check mark beside the answer, you can up-vote as well if you liked.